# What could I be missing with Prisma client, Cloud Run, and Cloud SQL - my Prisma client can't socket-connect to my Cloud SQL instance DB?

Tags: sockets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, prisma

**Background**

I have a NestJS project with Prisma ORM, and I am continually receiving the error:

```
PrismaClientInitializationError: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432`
```

This is happening during the Cloud Build Deploy step.

Since this is a containerized application (attempting to) run in a Cloud Run instance, I'm supposed to use a socket connection.  Here's the documentation from Prisma on connecting to a Postgres DB through a socket connection: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/postgresql#connecting-via-sockets

> **Connecting via sockets**

> To connect to your PostgreSQL database via sockets, you must add a host field as a query parameter to the connection URL (instead of setting it as the host part of the URI). The value of this parameter then must point to the directory that contains the socket, e.g.: postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@localhost/database?host=/var/run/postgresql/

> Note that localhost is required, the value itself is ignored and can be anything.

I've done this to the letter, as described in the Cloud SQL documentation, with the exception that I percent-encoded my path to the directory containing the socket.  I've included and excluded the trailing slash.

So my host var looks like this, mapped from the percent-encoded values:

```
/cloudsql/<MY CLOUD SQL CONNECTION NAME>/<DB>
```

I've read over the Cloud Run documentation, and in my mind, I should expect a different error if the instance itself can't connect to the Cloud SQL instance.  I've followed the "Make sure you have the appropriate permissions and connection" from the documentation a few times now.

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing?  Am I wrong about an error related to Cloud Run instance just not connecting with Cloud SQL instance?

**Things I've tried & things I know**

- I CAN connect directly to the Cloud SQL instance locally through psql
- I CAN run a local server with the Cloud SQL instance public IP and establish a client connection & interact with the database
- I CAN successfully create an image and run a container from that image locally

**My big concern**

It doesn't make sense to me in which order things should connect to the Cloud SQL instance.  To me, the Cloud Run - Cloud SQL connection MUST be established before the application run inside the Cloud Run instance can establish its connection through the socket to the Cloud SQL instance.  -- Am I thinking through that correctly?

Comment: 1) The Cloud SQL connection does not need to happen before the application. The proxy connects when the application requests a connection. The connection is proxied, not cached. 2) Why are you percent encoding the path? That path is not a URI, it is a filename to a Unix socket.

Comment: Thanks John.  It was my understanding that I had to percent-encode my whole URL string, as specified by Prisma.  I'll try it with the slashes and report back.

Comment: @JohnHanley - That was it!  Now my Cloud Run instance is routing traffic.  Cloud Build is still failing, and the Cloud Run instance has a "Trigger execution failed" error - but this is great progress.  If you would like to expound on your comment a bit as an answer, I would gladly accept it.  Other people lacking this experience could benefit from it too.

Comment: I see.  URI vs URL.  I'm still learning.